# selenium не находит элементы сайта

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

через какое-то время появляется капча на сайте, но сколько бы я не ставил времени

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"img[alt="Проверка"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)
```

Comment: элемент еще не успел загрузится, но селениум уже пытается что-то сделать, что и приводит к ошибке. [здесь, наверное, лучше объяснили](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27112731/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-unable-to-locate-ele)

Comment: Было бы весьма не плохо, увидеть HTML код и код которым вы этот элемент ищете.